# Adiabatic theorem - quantum mechanics and thermodynamics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, terminology, adiabatic

A [**diabatic process**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem) is defined as follows:

*Rapidly changing conditions prevent the system from adapting its configuration during the process, hence the spatial probability density remains unchanged. Typically there is no eigenstate of the final Hamiltonian with the same functional form as the initial state. The system ends in a linear combination of states that sum to reproduce the initial probability density.*

---

An [**adiabatic process**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem) is defined as follows:

*Gradually changing conditions allow the system to adapt its configuration, hence the probability density is modified by the process. If the system starts in an eigenstate of the initial Hamiltonian, it will end in the corresponding eigenstate of the final Hamiltonian.*

---

A diabatic process involves a *sudden* change of the Hamiltonian, while an adiabatic process involves a *gradual* change of the Hamiltonian.

The word *adiabatic*, in thermodynamics, is usually reserved for processes that do not involve the exchange of heat between the system and surroundings. Does this use of the word *adiabatic* have any relation to the use of the word *adiabatic* in quantum mechanics? How about the word *diabatic*?

Comment: [These slides](http://online.kitp.ucsb.edu/online/compqcm10/polkovnikov/pdf/Polkovnikov_CompQCM_KITP.pdf) seem to deal with the connection between the quantum and thermodynamical concept of adiabatic process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The notion of an adiabatic process in thermodynamics -vs- quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62126/)